# Resolve URL programmatically with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, url

I need to resolve the next url programmatically in JavaScript.

```
http://link.novemberfirst.com/ls/click?upn=xv2uBCiA-2BCPo8h2-2F2dXgSrKknBTgupgeogOdcsRpYXuG4cjYbJP1rkCCJ1zjXTj38aokCt-2BgUcrLMVeDJ0JrFznoH-2B4JC2bxKIUkkwWGvQPWZcW89yPA45cRI4YcN4kxIWOMamgXF7h0x-2BEumL4yC4cDPD6ib2Q-2FupSBTSJJvOohq9d3QApg3ktPsAr3s71dx8_f_jH2AkQSF6IE8lczSdagr9wUDFh2rSjc-2FDARefysokTdqaEnXNbSWSyYzYz4pIdy3KyzKI2WI84SAhUWA6Ysrwbu-2FEyv-2FLVj28UDJ96u9m0SfvfLMgVTTOypSpnfzJhz8HBp-2BErWzxw-2BHQBTWKJQCCsahFPt7FAp2yflzLocMroRH-2Blyqk-2Be61Q84U19yBAQ11beRliiLdNHnzJwd88-2FGbgPTIQoQi0xlVBQxVt08NyA-3D
```

Its a link generated by SendGrid and I need to get the resolved URL without involving a browser, is that possible?

The manual process would be to open that link on a browser and get the resolved url, but this is not an option.

Comment: I'm just tossing this out, but have you tried an ajax call with that url and see what headers it returns?

Comment: I have done a curl in unix and I am getting <a href="https://app-uat.novemberfirst.cloud.ec//#/public/reset-password/208100002/61849181%40abc.com/F1PMDcC05gYhlqh82UDnl183/dan/">Found</a>

Comment: Call this URL with Node.js? It runs Javascript and is not a browser